# Compiled ASP.NET application can be viewed locally only

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a development website running on my local machine, I can access it locally by typing the address http://mycomputer.mynetwork.local/myapp/default.aspx however when anybody else tries to browse to it they get an error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application. 
The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

I'm using IIS7, ASP.NET 3.5 and the application is pre-compiled.

Any hints?

Comment: have you tried pinging your machine from another machine.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue, or similar. You'll probably get better assistance on server fault.

Answer (score 0):

turned out to be a firewall issue, cheers